# How to display the tail of multiple files in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to monitor the progress of the newest five files and I want to see the last few lines of the each of them.

I was able to get the newest five files using the command:

```
ls *.log -lt | head -5
```

but I want to iterate through these five files and display the last 10 lines of each file. I was wondering if it can be done in a single bash command instead of a loop. But if it can't be done, I would appreciate a bash loop implementation too

Comment: Check http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tail` can take multiple file names.

```
tail -n 10 $(ls -t *.log | head -5)
```

Add `-F` to monitor them continuously for changes.

If the file names might have spaces `xargs` will be more robust:

```
ls -t *.log | head -5 | xargs -d '\n' tail -n 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the file names and path names do not contain special characters such as TAB or newline, how about:

```
while true; do
    find . -type f -name "*.log" -printf "%T@\t%p\n" | sort -n | tail -5 | cut -f2 | xargs tail -10
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: I am getting an error: `tail: option used in invalid context -- 1`

Comment: @Morpheus `-5` is not portable, try with `-n 5` instead

Comment: Haven't you aliased `tail` to something like `tail -20`?

Answer (score 1):

```
ls *.log -1t | head -5 | while IFS= read -r file; do tail -10 "$file"; done
```

Comment: I did change your code a little bit to have the file name print too `ls *.log -1t | head -5 | while read file; do echo "$file"; cat "$file" | tail -5; printf "\n"; done`

Comment: Sure. You must use a loop, as standard command will fail if there is a space in the file name.